# Find all facts matching a condition in Defrule

Tags: clips

I have two type of facts: state1 and state2, both are arrays of numbers. I want to check if a fact with tag 'state' with current value of state2 variable exists. How can I do it?

For example, if now facts are:
State 1 2 3
State2 4 5 6
State 0 8 9,
And current state2 is 1 2 3, I want to get into RHS because first row 'State 1 2 3' matches current value of State2.

I tried following solution, but I never enter RHS.

```
;;; END FUNCTION, EXECUTES WHEN SOLUTION WAS FOUND
(defrule complete (declare (salience 1000))
      (exists (state ?state2))
      => (printout t "Target state [1 2 3 8 0 4 7 6 5] reached" crlf) (halt)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defrule complete 
   (exists (state $?state)
           (state2 $?state))
    =>
    (printout t "Target state [1 2 3 8 0 4 7 6 5] reached" crlf))
CLIPS> 
(assert
   (state 1 2 3)
   (state2 4 5 6)
   (state 0 8 9)
   (state2 1 2 3))
<Fact-4>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      complete: *
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
Target state [1 2 3 8 0 4 7 6 5] reached
CLIPS>
```